# Facebook events graph API stopped working(Sep 2023)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the below URL to retrieve events on a page that I manage so that I don't need to submit an app review etc.

> https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/{page_id}/events/created/?fields=id,name,description,place,timezone,start_time,cover,ticket_uri&access_token={access_token}&limit=50

It works and has no errors, but it only returns a few results that are from years ago, the upcoming new events are all gone? Has anyone had this issue and what the reason could be?

It used to work fine and could return everything, but from yesterday something seems to have changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The endpoint you are using for events no longer exist as of mid-Sept 2023. I was having the exact same issue with older events showing up but none of the new events. Eventually, no events showed up at all.

I have had to redevelop a plugin I wrote for a charity website I manage to work with the New Pages on Facebook.

For over a year Facebook has been converting pages to "New Pages". When that was completed, the "events" API endpoint was completely removed and will not be returning. So anything you've developed has to be redeveloped.

Having said all of this, the "events" API endpoint has been deprecated for years now and was never officially supported in recent versions. It was only a matter of time before it disappeared.

Here is what I did to get my plugin working again. There are several hoops you have to jump through.

1. Use the Graph API Explorer to generate a Page access token https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
2. Use the explorer to generate your API endpoint URL.
3. I used the feed endpoint to get a listing of the last 10 post (using the pager parameter).

   `curl -i -X GET \ "https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/<your page ID goes here>/feed?access_token=<your access token here>"`
4. After returning a list of posts, I created an array then I searched through them (via code) to find the ones that are events. These are marked as "story" and will usually contain " has added an event" or something close to that. I basically just did an if statement for this:

   ```
   foreach($fbposts as $post){
     if($post->story == '<your page name> created an event.'){

       $subject = $post->id;
       $search = '<your page ID>_' ;
       $trimmed_id = str_replace($search, '', $subject) ;

       $new_ids[] = array(
         'event_id' => $trimmed_id,
       );

     }
   }
   ```
5. I created an array of those events, and then used the "event" API endpoint to query each one.

   `curl -i -X GET \ "https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/<your event ID here>?fields=name%2Cdescription%2Cstart_time%2Ccover&access_token=<your access token here>"`
6. Once you return your event data, you can do whatever you want with it. I used it to create a new array with all of my events information.

This is likely not the best way to do this, but it's the only way I could figure out how to get events. Facebook hasn't documented any of this or provided ways to get events in a list, and they haven't responded to any of my support tickets.

I hope that helps!

Comment: if its deprecated why they still leave it in docs and allow to query over the new api versions.....

but at least it makes sense why it stopped working. thx

Comment: They did that because they were giving people time to stop using it. It's been deprecated since July 1, 2022. After that, they started moving pages to the "New Pages". I believe that migration is complete and so the Events API has been completely removed at this point. You will not find it in the docs at all in new API versions.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated 20th Sep**

It doesn't look like it will be fixed soon or ever will be. There is an alternative method that you can get event data by its ID like below. Apparently, you need to know the ID first, we are manually adding the IDs at the moment as I don't know how to automatically get them.

> [https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/{$event_id}/?fields={$fields}&access_token={$access_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/%7B$event_id%7D/?fields=%7B$fields%7D&access_token=%7B$access_token%7D)

==============================================================

Okay, after hours of research, it's confirmed that this is a Facebook API issue and there is nothing we can do but just wait I believe. Hope this helps.

Comment: The Facebook "events" API endpoint has been deprecated for years and has been officially turned off as of mid-Sept. I highly doubt it will be returning. I've posted a solution that I used to get events. It's jumping through a few hoops, but works.

Answer (score -1):

Same issue here since yesterday, but looking the docs I cannot even find the endpoint /{page_id}/events in version v17... I found something like "official_events" but that endpoint doesn't work with /{page_id}

Comment: The Facebook "events" API endpoint has been deprecated for years and has been officially turned off as of mid-Sept. I highly doubt it will be returning. I've posted my solution for getting events. You have to first get the feed for your page and then use that list to get your events using the individual event ID.